# как вывести результат выполнения exec() в файл

Tags: php

Всем привет. Никак не могу разобрать, пытаюсь написать скрипт, который будет вызывать другой скрипт в консоли:

exec('/srv/www/zf2/public/info.php >> /srv/www/zf2/logs/console.log&')

внутри /srv/www/zf2/public/info.php простое echo, результат которого я хочу увидеть в файле. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Тут я думаю дело в пути файла

Comment: @newProgrammer путь все в порядке, удаляю в директории такой файл, запускаю скрипт, появляется пустой файл.

Comment: `php -f /srv/www/zf2/public/info.php` наверное так всё таки, но не мешало бы исходный код `info.php` предоставить

Comment: p.s. смысл то это делать?

Comment: все же ради страховки для путей используйте `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Comment: @Naumov, то что вы написали я должен написать внутрь exec? или в консоль? смысл в том чтобы вернуть пользователю в браузер ответ и запустить при этом достаточно долгий скрипт.

Comment: Тогда смысла нет так запускать юзайте `pthreads` или `cron` с очередью задач